# Recommended Drush version to use and install for Ubuntu 19 with PHP 7.2 and running Drupal 7

Tags: 7, drush, composer

It's been awhile since I've upgraded my server and I'm setting it up from scratch. I'm using Ubuntu 19, apache 2 and PHP 7.2. My site is Drupal 7 which is still running php 5.6 in my old server. I'm in the process of installing drush via the command on the new server:

> composer global require drush/drush:8

I'm not sure which version of drush I should be using or if I should even be installing via that method. What version of Drush should I be using for Drupal 7 and am I using the correct PHP version of 7.2?

Comment: "Please do not install Drush using composer global require" from http://docs.drush.org/en/8.x/install/

Comment: Hey Patoshi, asking to recommend tools is off-topic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drush 9 does not work with drupal 7, but drush 8 does work with it. I installed it by creating a new ubuntu user and making sure composer is installed globally then install cgr via:

**composer global require consolidation/cgr**

then add to your ~/.bashrc file

**export PATH="$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"**

then

**cgr drush/drush:8.x-dev --prefer-source**

link: https://github.com/consolidation/cgr#installation-and-usage

Then I followed the tutorial here: https://docs.drush.org/en/8.x/install-alternative/

> Install a global Drush via Composer
>
> Follow the instructions below:
>
> Install Composer globally.
>
> Install the cgr tool following the instructions in that project.
>
> Add composer's bin directory to the system path by placing export 
>   PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH" into your ~/.bash_profile (Mac
>   OS users) or into your ~/.bashrc (Linux users).
>
> Install latest stable Drush: cgr drush/drush.
>
> Verify that Drush works: drush status
>
> Please do not install Drush using composer global require. See Fixing
>   the Composer Global command for more information.

Comment: fyi, this method still works as of 1/27/2021